# why DSolve gives different looking solution when using u vs. u[x,t] in the call?

Tags: differential-equations

Should the answer by `DSolve` be different when calling it as `DSolve[ode,u,{x,t}]` vs. `DSolve[ode,u[x,t],{x,t}]`?

In 11.3, `DSolve` gives different looking solution using `u[x,t]` vs. `u`. In addition, when using `u[x,t]` the answer contains a constant `C[1]` which is not even there when using `u`, so one can't plot the solution as the help page does.

I do not understand why the solution look different.  Here is the MWE. This comes from Mathematica http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html?view=all  the example about down half the page, under title

> Initial value problem for the wave equation with a Neumann condition
>   on the half-line:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[u, x, t];
weqn=D[u[x,t],{t,2}]==D[u[x,t],{x,2}];
ic={u[x,0]==Sin[x]^3,Derivative[0,1][u][x,0]==1-E^(-x/10)};
bc=Derivative[1,0][u][0,t]==1;
sol=DSolve[{weqn,ic,bc},u,{x,t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol=DSolve[{weqn,ic,bc},u[x,t],{x,t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why the solution look different? Why one has `C[1]` in it and the other does not? Should the answers look the same always, except for the use of `Function` in one case?  Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you try what happens if you use `DSolveValue` in your second example? For me, it then creates the first form.

Comment: With `DSolveValue` on `11.2` both outputs are the same now.